# Get secret from multiple hashicorp vaults in one gitlab CI/CD job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, hashicorp-vault, vault

I want to know if it is possible, then how can I fetch secrets from 2 different hashicorp vault in one CI/CD job.

I have two vault servers, so there will be two **VAULT_SERVER_URL** with different **Role** and **Token**.

I tried to get secret from one vault but i need it from 2, i have separate vault for each environment

For example:

```yaml
read_secret_via_token-id:
  stage: get_secret
  image: vault:1.13.3
  variables:
    VAULT_SERVER_URL: <vault-server-url->
    VAULT_AUTH_ROLE: <role>
  id_tokens:
    VAULT_ID_TOKEN:
      aud: <gitlab-url>
  secrets:
    POSTGRES_USERNAME:
      vault: database/postgres/postgres_username@kv2
      token: $VAULT_ID_TOKEN
      file: false
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD:
      vault: database/postgres/postgres_password@kv2
      token: $VAULT_ID_TOKEN
      file: false
  script:
    - echo "Fetched secret"
    - echo POSTGRES_USERNAME | base64
    - echo POSTGRES_PASSWORD | base64`
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Better code visibility

read_secret_via_token-id:
  stage: get_secret
  image: vault:1.13.3
  variables:
    VAULT_SERVER_URL: <vault-server-url->
    VAULT_AUTH_ROLE: <role>
  id_tokens:
    VAULT_ID_TOKEN:
      aud: <gitlab-url>
  secrets:
    POSTGRES_USERNAME:
      vault: database/postgres/postgres_username@kv2
      token: $VAULT_ID_TOKEN
      file: false
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD:
      vault: database/postgres/postgres_password@kv2
      token: $VAULT_ID_TOKEN
      file: false
  script:
    - echo POSTGRES_USERNAME | base64
    - echo POSTGRES_PASSWORD | base64

Comment: Do you need to work with multiple environments in a single CI/CD job? Why not handle each environment (and its associated secrets) in separate jobs?